# Do the words "dolphin" and "الدلفين" in English and Arabic have the same origin?

Tags: etymology, arabic

The word *dolphin* is used in may languages including English and Arabic ([الدلفين](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%86/))

But it seems Arabic dictionaries say originally it has been *darfil* while Oxford dictionary says it is derived from the Greek word *delfin*.

Also I have found an old Arabic text (1000 years ago) in which the word الدلفين is used.

Do they have the same origin in Arabic and English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arabic dulfīn is a loan word from Aramaic (in Syriac dolfin or delfin), which in turn is borrowed from Greek. dulfīl is a variant in Arabic. You can find a fluctuation between final /n/ and /l/ in other words, e.g. finjān vs. finjāl. So, yes, both English and Arabic have this name ultimately from Greek.